# How to add all of a specific element name to a list in Python using a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7 and the normal JSON module, how could I go about putting all of the "accountName" variables in a list?

```
{"accounts":[
    {   "accountName":"US Account", 
        "firstName":"Jackson"
    },
    {   "accountName":"Orange Account", 
        "firstName":"Micheal"
    },
    {   "accountName":"f safasf", 
        "firstName":"Andrew"
    }
]}
```

I've tried:

```
x = 0
accountsList = []

for Accounts['accountName'] in Accounts['accounts'][x]:
    accountsList.append(accountName)
    print accountsList
    x = x + 1
```

But I know that's incredibly wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a list comprehension, like this:

```
accountsList = [x["accountName"] for x in Accounts["accounts"]]
```

A list comprehension is like a mini `for`-loop which generates a list as it goes through another iterable.

Answer (score 1):

With a list comprehension, you can do:

```
[account["accountName"] for account in Accounts["accounts"]]
Out[13]: ['US Account', 'Orange Account', 'f safasf']
```

This is similar to what you are doing, only the loop is:

```
accountsList = []
for account in Accounts["accounts"]: #because the "accounts" key gives a list
    accountsList.append(account["accountName"]) #under that list, there are 3 dictionaries and you want the key "accountName" of each dictionary
```